# Why does $e^{-x}$ approach $0$ as $x$ gets large?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

Why is it that

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0?$$

Context:
College has started back up again and I like to understand the reasons why things do the things they do, rather than just memorizing. I'm sure i've seen it before - but I am coming up with a blank today.

Comment: Graph the function out that will show you.

Comment: This is easier if you think about it with $10$ instead of $e$. $10^{-100}=0.000\dots001$ is very small, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint.** One may recall that

> $$
> e^{-x}=\frac1{e^x}
> $$

Comment: Wow. Hah. Thank you. I'm surprised i didn't notice such a fundamental explanation.

Answer (score 10):

The guiding question goes like this: What happens when you divide $1$ by a really, really large number?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the graph:

[image]

Notice what happens when you go from a negative number to a positive number.